# local host cannot be found Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, localhost

I cannot debug/test my .Net website. I keep getting local host cannot be found error. It used to work fine but the past few days its been coming up with an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Sorry for the confusion in the images below, as you can see the port number is different to the one being displayed in the VS. I was trying to open a different project and run it, so I got the wrong pic up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What changed in your setup or project settings?

Comment: Do you have a server running?

Comment: @SLaks hmm how do you check? Sorry am not good with the technical

Comment: Do you see the VS Dev server in the notification area?

Comment: @SLaks I can see the server in the Server Explorer in VS

Comment: It says "cannot find", it doesn't say "cannot connect".  Proxy setup or anti-malware is my guess.

Comment: @HansPassant so any idea how can i fix it if thats the case?

Comment: As long as you can't give better feedback, undo whatever you did a couple of days ago.  Restore points are good for that, ask at superuser.com

Comment: @HansPassant what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

From the url in your browser, the address is bound to a port 49974. You get this error sometimes when this port is no longer available. Go to your Visual Studio and press F5 again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project properties. Go to the Web Page and look which server VS use to run your project.
Usually this is the Visual Studio Development Server with automatic port selection.
Next check the notification area near on the right bottom of the application bar. Here, there is the little up arrow which sould contain the icon for the Visual Studio Development Server. If you hover the icon you can see the port used by the Development Server. The two ports should be the same.

On the other cases, if you have selected Local IIS or another server you need to have these servers installed and available and running on the same port of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues for past two days

The thing I did was that created new MVC project from scratch running it and then running my project if its working then fine.

If not than compare their csproj file and change the IIS things with the new project from scratch than paste it in .csproj file it will run like a charm.